# Combinatorial symmetric CV vs Combinatorial purged CV

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, cross-validation, finance

Reading "Advances in Financial Machine Learning", and the author proposes 2 methods of CV: "combinatorial symmetric cross validation" (11.6) and "combinatorial purged cross validation" (12.4)

While I understand these methods, I'm a bit unclear in the uses cases that differentiate them.  My understanding: combinatorial purged CV is an alternative to the traditional backtest where you seek to validate (falsify) some hypothesis/strategy (sort of like a feasibility study), while combinatorial symmetric CV could be a later step in your workflow, where you've already validated your strategy and are simply seeking optimal parameterizations for it.

It also seems CPCV is a little more versatile / rigorous than CSCV as it allows partition you training/test as you see fit (whereas CPCV defaults to 50/50).  Assuming you subject your CPCV validated hypothesis to CSCV, and find some parametrization  that outperforms the one you initially tested via CPCV, you could simply run it through CPCV again to check for robustness, no?

Is this the main difference in application?  Can someone clarify?

Comment: would love to see an answer to this question. I am also a bit puzzled by the CSCV method after reading the probability of backtest overfitting paper. Based on the examples the paper used, it seems like CSCV can be used to find the optimal profit take and stop loss levels apart from just measuring the probability of backtest overfitting. Am i getting this wrong ?